# Not able to Sort Url Column in LWC Datatable

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

i am trying to build datatable where I want to show Product Name as url so that User can go that particular record

JS where i am making my name field as URL

```
 {   
     let nameUrl;
     this.showSpinner = false;
     this.allProducts = result.map(row =>{
     nameUrl = `/${row.Id}`;
     return {...row,nameUrl}
  });
```

Now when I am trying to sort "nameUrl" in my datatable the sort direction stays "asc" and doesn't change to "desc" even after clicking multiple time. I am not able to understand why this is happening. When i am using the same sort function for any other field it works perfectly fine. Can anyone let me know where i am wrong and how i can rectify the same

JS file for my Data Table

```
export default class SearchProductDataTable extends LightningElement {
@api products;
@track sortBy;
@track sortDirection;
@track allProducts;
@track prodNameObject = [];
cols = columns;


handleSortdata(event){

    let sortbyField= event.detail.fieldName;
    if(sortbyField ==='nameUrl'){
        this.sortBy = 'Name'; 
    } else{
        this.sortBy = sortbyField;

    }
    this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    console.log('This is the sort direction ',this.sortDirection);
    //Console Log : When nameUrl field is clicked Sort Direction is always 'asc'
    this.sortData(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
}

sortData(fieldName, sortDirection){
    let data =  [...this.products];
    console.log('This is the sort value of nameurl ',fieldName);
    //function to return the value stored in the field
    let key =(a) => a[fieldName]; 
    //console.log('This is key value ',key);
    let reverse = sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1: -1;
    data.sort((a,b) => {
        let valueA = key(a) ? key(a).toLowerCase() : '';
        let valueB = key(b) ? key(b).toLowerCase() : '';
        console.log('This is Value A',valueA);
        console.log('This is Value B',valueB);
        let vale = (valueA > valueB) - (valueB > valueA);
        console.log('This is Vale ',vale);
        console.log('This is the value of reverse',reverse);
        return reverse * ((valueA > valueB) - (valueB > valueA));
    });
    this.products = data;

}

get showTable(){
    if(this.products.length > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Data Table Columns :

```
const columns = [
{
    label:'Prd Record Link',
    fieldName:'nameUrl',
    type:'url',
    typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, 
                    target: '_blank'},
    sortable: true,
    wrapText: true
},
{
    label: 'Product Name',
    fieldName:'Name',
    type:'text',
    sortable:true,
    wrapText: true
},
{
    label: 'Product Code',
    fieldName:'ProductCode',
    type:'text',
    sortable:true,
    wrapText: true
},
{
    label:'Eng Status',
    fieldName:'Eng_Status__c',
    type:'text',
    hideDefaultActions:true
},
{
    label:'Quotable',
    fieldName:'Quotable__c',
    type:'text',
    hideDefaultActions:true
},
{
    label:'Quoting Rules',
    fieldName:'Quoting_Rules__c',
    type:'text',
    hideDefaultActions:true
},
{
    label:'USD Price',
    fieldName:'USD_Price__c',
    type:'currency',
    typeAttributes:{currencyCode: 'USD'},
    hideDefaultActions:true
},
{
    label:'AUD Price',
    fieldName:'AUD_Price__c',
    type:'currency',
    typeAttributes:{currencyCode: 'AUD'},
    hideDefaultActions:true
},
{
    label:'CAD Price',
    fieldName:'CAD_Price__c',
    type:'currency',
    typeAttributes:{currencyCode: 'CAD'},
    hideDefaultActions:true
},
{
    label:'China Price',
    fieldName:'China_Price__c',
    type:'currency',
    typeAttributes:{currencyCode: 'CNY'},
    hideDefaultActions:true
},
{
    label:'EUR Price',
    fieldName:'EUR_Price__c',
    type:'currency',
    typeAttributes:{currencyCode: 'EUR'},
    hideDefaultActions:true
},
{
    label:'GBP Price',
    fieldName:'GBP_Price__c',
    type:'currency',
    typeAttributes:{currencyCode: 'GBP'},
    hideDefaultActions:true
}];
```

Comment: Can you give the data (in JSON) you are getting?

Comment: Hi JSON is fine the challenge is when i click on nameUrl column the sortDirection always stays "asc" because of which first time data get sorted perfectly but when I click second time to show reverse direction the sort direction still remain "asc"

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, because it appears that this is your problem. Note that in LWC, attribute names will be `sorted-by` and `sorted-direction` instead. If you're still having problems, please let us know and I'll be glad to reopen the question for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox in my data table i have used the attribute name correctly as mentioned by you and the sorting function is working perfectly fine with other columns like "Product Code" and "Product Name" only when I click on my custom column nameUrl the sort direction always stays "asc"

Comment: @AbhishekKhosla have you solved this? I am also stuck with same issue.

Answer (score 4):

The `fieldName` attribute on the column needs to match `sortBy`, assuming you have that bound to `sorted-by` on the datatable:

> To enable sorting of row data by a column label, set sortable to true
> for the column on which you want to enable sorting. **Set sortedBy to
> match the fieldName attribute on the column**. Clicking a column header
> sorts rows by ascending order unless the defaultSortDirection is
> changed, and clicking it subsequently reverses the order. Handle the
> onsort event handler to update the table with the new column index and
> sort direction.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation

Thus if you're sorting a column using a custom attribute, you could try just setting `sortBy` to match the `fieldName` attribute after the data is sorted:

```
handleSortdata(event) {
  let sortbyField = event.detail.fieldName;
  if (sortbyField === "nameUrl") {
    this.sortBy = "Name";
  } else {
    this.sortBy = sortbyField;
  }
  this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
  this.sortData(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
  this.sortBy = sortbyField;
}
```